# Turing Machine to Generate Fibonacchi series

Tags: computation-theory, turing-machines

Is it possible (as shown in following image), for given number of consecutive 1's in turing machine's tape, to generate fibonacchi series  of given pattern: (Following image represents fibonacchi series of length 5, & consider '0' to represent first element of series))

Link for Image:  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AY3CL.png

Comment: Guess you cannot be bothered to do your homework. What makes you think other people would like to do it?

Comment: I don't understand the constraint don't use multi tapes. As you can always simulate a multitape with a single tape.

Comment: Yes, multitape can be simulated by single tape, but how to describe its final state, since no. of 1's should generate according to pattern shown in image.(with two tapes, it's easy to describe it's final state)